# display an Array on Html page with Ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs, display

I make a little forum for my website with Ejs/NodeJs/MongoDb , when a user post a object is create (title: , comment : , reply:[] , i need an array for the reply because there is multiple , i managed to display my titles in different Html elements , the comment too but when i try to display the reply that display all the reply in one "

"...
this is my code :

```
        <div  class="vosQuestions" id="vosQuestions" >
            <% for(var i = 0; i < collectionName.length; i++) {%>
                
            <div class="result">
                <span id="titreResultat" class="titreResultat"><%=collectionName[i].title%></span>
                
                <div id="commentQuestions" class="commentOff">
                    
                        
                        <p class="comment"><%=collectionName[i].commentaire%></p> 
                       
                    <div class="trait"></div>
                    
                    
                    <p class="repArray"><%=collectionName[i].reponse%></p>
                    <p id="rep2">
                       
            
                    <div id="test" class="reprep">
                        <input  id="repBtn" class="repondre" type="button" value="repondre">
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </div>
               
            </div>
            
            
            <%} %>
```

Comment: is `<p class="repArray"><%=collectionName[i].reponse%></p>` where you want to display the reply?

Comment: right , i want to create a "<p>" element for each reply

Comment: You need a 2nd, inner loop that iterates over `collectionName[i].reponse` in exactly the same way as you already iterate over `collectionName`.

Comment: ok but i cant do  <% for(var i = 0; i < collectionName.reponse.length; i++) {%>..

Answer (score 0):

as you have replied in the comments on your question, `<p class="repArray"><%=collectionName[i].reponse%></p>` is where you want to display the reply.

the reason that it is displaying all the reply in one go (probably in JSON format) is because reply or `response` is an array. in order to wrap each "reply" or `response` inside a `<p>` element, you have to iterate or loop through each one of them.

use the code below as a reference.

```
for (let i = 0; i < replies.length; i++)
{
    <p class="repArray"><%= replies[i] %></p>
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but is not really possible because i need to display the own reply of the subject , for display the collection with node my code is that :    app.get("/vosQuestions",async (req,res)=>{    
      try{
       
      const db = client.db('dedDB');

      
      
     db.collection('POST').find().toArray(function(err, result){
        
        if (err) { return console.log(err) }

       

        res.render("vosQuestions",{collectionName: result })
      })

Comment: by looping through the collectionName[i].response array, you can display those reply one by one

Comment: haha that i try to do .. but i can't do : <% for(var i = 0; i < collectionName.reponse.length; i++) {%>     how i can do this ?

Comment: what does your `collectionName[0].response` return?

Comment: the reply array from the first object

Comment: then you can do `collectionName[0].response['property_name']` or `collectionName[0].response->property_name` to display the data

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand what is "property_name" .. i can't write collectionName[0].response , collectionName[1].response , ect ect because all is created dynamically ..